jazzy ros2 does not recognize rclcpp::ok(), rclcpp::sleep_for()
We just updated our robot stack from ROS2 Iron to ROS2 Jazzy, and we are facing a problem, when we are building package, we receive a build error, that ok() and sleep_for() is not a member of rclcpp
Starting >>> stage_ros2
--- stderr: stage_ros2                             
In file included from /usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/FL/x.H:37,
                 from /usr/include/FL/fl_draw.H:27,
                 from /home/peter/colcon_ws/install/Stage/include/Stage-4.3/stage.hh:64,
                 from /home/peter/colcon_ws/src/stage_ros2/./include/stage_ros2/stage_node.hpp:14,
                 from /home/peter/colcon_ws/src/stage_ros2/src/ranger.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:56:3: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
   56 |   None,
      |   ^~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:56:3: error: expected ‘}’ before numeric constant
In file included from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/logging.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/copy_all_parameter_values.hpp:27,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:171,
                 from /home/peter/colcon_ws/src/stage_ros2/./include/stage_ros2/stage_node.hpp:17:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:48:1: note: to match this ‘{’
   48 | {
      | ^
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:56:3: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
   56 |   None,
      |   ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/FL/x.H:37,
                 from /usr/include/FL/fl_draw.H:27,
                 from /home/peter/colcon_ws/install/Stage/include/Stage-4.3/stage.hh:64,
                 from /home/peter/colcon_ws/src/stage_ros2/./include/stage_ros2/stage_node.hpp:14,
                 from /home/peter/colcon_ws/src/stage_ros2/src/camera.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:56:3: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
   56 |   None,
      |   ^~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:56:3: error: expected ‘}’ before numeric constant
In file included from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/logging.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/copy_all_parameter_values.hpp:27,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:171,
                 from /home/peter/colcon_ws/src/stage_ros2/./include/stage_ros2/stage_node.hpp:17:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:48:1: note: to match this ‘{’
   48 | {
      | ^
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:56:3: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
   56 |   None,
      |   ^~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:78:9: error: ‘InitOptions’ does not name a type
   78 |   const InitOptions & init_options = InitOptions(),
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:78:38: error: ‘InitOptions’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘rclcpp::InitOptions’?
   78 |   const InitOptions & init_options = InitOptions(),
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      rclcpp::InitOptions
In file included from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/context.hpp:34,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:24:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/init_options.hpp:28:7: note: ‘rclcpp::InitOptions’ declared here
   28 | class InitOptions
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:79:3: error: ‘SignalHandlerOptions’ has not been declared
   79 |   SignalHandlerOptions signal_handler_options = SignalHandlerOptions::All);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:79:49: error: ‘SignalHandlerOptions’ has not been declared
   79 |   SignalHandlerOptions signal_handler_options = SignalHandlerOptions::All);
      |                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:98:25: error: ‘SignalHandlerOptions’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘rclcpp::SignalHandlerOptions’?
   98 | install_signal_handlers(SignalHandlerOptions signal_handler_options = SignalHandlerOptions::All);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                         rclcpp::SignalHandlerOptions
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:47:12: note: ‘rclcpp::SignalHandlerOptions’ declared here
   47 | enum class SignalHandlerOptions
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:78:9: error: ‘InitOptions’ does not name a type
   78 |   const InitOptions & init_options = InitOptions(),
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:78:38: error: ‘InitOptions’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘rclcpp::InitOptions’?
   78 |   const InitOptions & init_options = InitOptions(),
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      rclcpp::InitOptions
In file included from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/context.hpp:34,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:24:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/init_options.hpp:28:7: note: ‘rclcpp::InitOptions’ declared here
   28 | class InitOptions
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:79:3: error: ‘SignalHandlerOptions’ has not been declared
   79 |   SignalHandlerOptions signal_handler_options = SignalHandlerOptions::All);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:79:49: error: ‘SignalHandlerOptions’ has not been declared
   79 |   SignalHandlerOptions signal_handler_options = SignalHandlerOptions::All);
      |                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:98:25: error: ‘SignalHandlerOptions’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘rclcpp::SignalHandlerOptions’?
   98 | install_signal_handlers(SignalHandlerOptions signal_handler_options = SignalHandlerOptions::All);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                         rclcpp::SignalHandlerOptions
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:47:12: note: ‘rclcpp::SignalHandlerOptions’ declared here
   47 | enum class SignalHandlerOptions
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:110:1: error: ‘SignalHandlerOptions’ does not name a type
  110 | SignalHandlerOptions
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:110:1: error: ‘SignalHandlerOptions’ does not name a type
  110 | SignalHandlerOptions
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:143:9: error: ‘InitOptions’ does not name a type
  143 |   const InitOptions & init_options = InitOptions());
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:143:38: error: ‘InitOptions’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘rclcpp::InitOptions’?
  143 |   const InitOptions & init_options = InitOptions());
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      rclcpp::InitOptions
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/init_options.hpp:28:7: note: ‘rclcpp::InitOptions’ declared here
   28 | class InitOptions
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:333:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
  333 | }  // namespace rclcpp
      | ^
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:143:9: error: ‘InitOptions’ does not name a type
  143 |   const InitOptions & init_options = InitOptions());
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:143:38: error: ‘InitOptions’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘rclcpp::InitOptions’?
  143 |   const InitOptions & init_options = InitOptions());
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      rclcpp::InitOptions
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/init_options.hpp:28:7: note: ‘rclcpp::InitOptions’ declared here
   28 | class InitOptions
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:333:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
  333 | }  // namespace rclcpp
      | ^
In file included from /usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/FL/x.H:37,
                 from /usr/include/FL/fl_draw.H:27,
                 from /home/peter/colcon_ws/install/Stage/include/Stage-4.3/stage.hh:64,
                 from /home/peter/colcon_ws/src/stage_ros2/./include/stage_ros2/stage_node.hpp:14,
                 from /home/peter/colcon_ws/src/stage_ros2/src/stage_node.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:56:3: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
   56 |   None,
      |   ^~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:56:3: error: expected ‘}’ before numeric constant
In file included from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/logging.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/copy_all_parameter_values.hpp:27,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:171,
                 from /home/peter/colcon_ws/src/stage_ros2/./include/stage_ros2/stage_node.hpp:17:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:48:1: note: to match this ‘{’
   48 | {
      | ^
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:56:3: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
   56 |   None,
      |   ^~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:78:9: error: ‘InitOptions’ does not name a type
   78 |   const InitOptions & init_options = InitOptions(),
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:78:38: error: ‘InitOptions’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘rclcpp::InitOptions’?
   78 |   const InitOptions & init_options = InitOptions(),
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      rclcpp::InitOptions
In file included from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/context.hpp:34,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:24:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/init_options.hpp:28:7: note: ‘rclcpp::InitOptions’ declared here
   28 | class InitOptions
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:79:3: error: ‘SignalHandlerOptions’ has not been declared
   79 |   SignalHandlerOptions signal_handler_options = SignalHandlerOptions::All);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:79:49: error: ‘SignalHandlerOptions’ has not been declared
   79 |   SignalHandlerOptions signal_handler_options = SignalHandlerOptions::All);
      |                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:98:25: error: ‘SignalHandlerOptions’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘rclcpp::SignalHandlerOptions’?
   98 | install_signal_handlers(SignalHandlerOptions signal_handler_options = SignalHandlerOptions::All);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                         rclcpp::SignalHandlerOptions
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:47:12: note: ‘rclcpp::SignalHandlerOptions’ declared here
   47 | enum class SignalHandlerOptions
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:110:1: error: ‘SignalHandlerOptions’ does not name a type
  110 | SignalHandlerOptions
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:143:9: error: ‘InitOptions’ does not name a type
  143 |   const InitOptions & init_options = InitOptions());
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:143:38: error: ‘InitOptions’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘rclcpp::InitOptions’?
  143 |   const InitOptions & init_options = InitOptions());
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      rclcpp::InitOptions
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/init_options.hpp:28:7: note: ‘rclcpp::InitOptions’ declared here
   28 | class InitOptions
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:333:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
  333 | }  // namespace rclcpp
      | ^
In file included from /usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/FL/x.H:37,
                 from /usr/include/FL/fl_draw.H:27,
                 from /home/peter/colcon_ws/install/Stage/include/Stage-4.3/stage.hh:64,
                 from /home/peter/colcon_ws/src/stage_ros2/./include/stage_ros2/stage_node.hpp:14,
                 from /home/peter/colcon_ws/src/stage_ros2/src/vehicle.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:56:3: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
   56 |   None,
      |   ^~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:56:3: error: expected ‘}’ before numeric constant
In file included from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/logging.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/copy_all_parameter_values.hpp:27,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:171,
                 from /home/peter/colcon_ws/src/stage_ros2/./include/stage_ros2/stage_node.hpp:17:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:48:1: note: to match this ‘{’
   48 | {
      | ^
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:56:3: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
   56 |   None,
      |   ^~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:78:9: error: ‘InitOptions’ does not name a type
   78 |   const InitOptions & init_options = InitOptions(),
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:78:38: error: ‘InitOptions’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘rclcpp::InitOptions’?
   78 |   const InitOptions & init_options = InitOptions(),
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      rclcpp::InitOptions
In file included from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/context.hpp:34,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:24:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/init_options.hpp:28:7: note: ‘rclcpp::InitOptions’ declared here
   28 | class InitOptions
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:79:3: error: ‘SignalHandlerOptions’ has not been declared
   79 |   SignalHandlerOptions signal_handler_options = SignalHandlerOptions::All);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:79:49: error: ‘SignalHandlerOptions’ has not been declared
   79 |   SignalHandlerOptions signal_handler_options = SignalHandlerOptions::All);
      |                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:98:25: error: ‘SignalHandlerOptions’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘rclcpp::SignalHandlerOptions’?
   98 | install_signal_handlers(SignalHandlerOptions signal_handler_options = SignalHandlerOptions::All);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                         rclcpp::SignalHandlerOptions
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:47:12: note: ‘rclcpp::SignalHandlerOptions’ declared here
   47 | enum class SignalHandlerOptions
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:110:1: error: ‘SignalHandlerOptions’ does not name a type
  110 | SignalHandlerOptions
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:143:9: error: ‘InitOptions’ does not name a type
  143 |   const InitOptions & init_options = InitOptions());
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:143:38: error: ‘InitOptions’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘rclcpp::InitOptions’?
  143 |   const InitOptions & init_options = InitOptions());
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                      rclcpp::InitOptions
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/init_options.hpp:28:7: note: ‘rclcpp::InitOptions’ declared here
   28 | class InitOptions
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:333:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
  333 | }  // namespace rclcpp
      | ^
In file included from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/timer.hpp:32,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/callback_group.hpp:30,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/any_executable.hpp:20,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/memory_strategy.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/memory_strategies.hpp:18,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executor_options.hpp:22,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executor.hpp:38,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors/multi_threaded_executor.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors.hpp:21,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:172:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rate.hpp: In member function ‘virtual bool rclcpp::GenericRate<Clock>::sleep()’:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rate.hpp:98:13: error: ‘sleep_for’ is not a member of ‘rclcpp’
   98 |     rclcpp::sleep_for(time_to_sleep);
      |             ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rate.hpp:98:13: note: suggested alternatives:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:232:1: note:   ‘sleep_for’
  232 | sleep_for(
      | ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/13/thread:46,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors/multi_threaded_executor.hpp:22:
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/this_thread_sleep.h:68:7: note:   ‘std::this_thread::sleep_for’
   68 |       sleep_for(const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& __rtime)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/timer.hpp:32,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/callback_group.hpp:30,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/any_executable.hpp:20,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/memory_strategy.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/memory_strategies.hpp:18,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executor_options.hpp:22,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executor.hpp:38,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors/multi_threaded_executor.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors.hpp:21,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:172:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rate.hpp: In member function ‘virtual bool rclcpp::GenericRate<Clock>::sleep()’:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rate.hpp:98:13: error: ‘sleep_for’ is not a member of ‘rclcpp’
   98 |     rclcpp::sleep_for(time_to_sleep);
      |             ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rate.hpp:98:13: note: suggested alternatives:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:232:1: note:   ‘sleep_for’
  232 | sleep_for(
      | ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/13/thread:46,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors/multi_threaded_executor.hpp:22:
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/this_thread_sleep.h:68:7: note:   ‘std::this_thread::sleep_for’
   68 |       sleep_for(const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& __rtime)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/timer.hpp:32,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/callback_group.hpp:30,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/any_executable.hpp:20,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/memory_strategy.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/memory_strategies.hpp:18,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executor_options.hpp:22,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executor.hpp:38,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors/multi_threaded_executor.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors.hpp:21,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:172:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rate.hpp: In member function ‘virtual bool rclcpp::GenericRate<Clock>::sleep()’:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rate.hpp:98:13: error: ‘sleep_for’ is not a member of ‘rclcpp’
   98 |     rclcpp::sleep_for(time_to_sleep);
      |             ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rate.hpp:98:13: note: suggested alternatives:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:232:1: note:   ‘sleep_for’
  232 | sleep_for(
      | ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/13/thread:46,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors/multi_threaded_executor.hpp:22:
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/this_thread_sleep.h:68:7: note:   ‘std::this_thread::sleep_for’
   68 |       sleep_for(const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& __rtime)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/timer.hpp:32,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/callback_group.hpp:30,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/any_executable.hpp:20,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/memory_strategy.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/memory_strategies.hpp:18,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executor_options.hpp:22,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executor.hpp:38,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors/multi_threaded_executor.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors.hpp:21,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:172:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rate.hpp: In member function ‘virtual bool rclcpp::GenericRate<Clock>::sleep()’:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rate.hpp:98:13: error: ‘sleep_for’ is not a member of ‘rclcpp’
   98 |     rclcpp::sleep_for(time_to_sleep);
      |             ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rate.hpp:98:13: note: suggested alternatives:
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:232:1: note:   ‘sleep_for’
  232 | sleep_for(
      | ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/13/thread:46,
                 from /opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors/multi_threaded_executor.hpp:22:
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/this_thread_sleep.h:68:7: note:   ‘std::this_thread::sleep_for’
   68 |       sleep_for(const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& __rtime)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
/home/peter/colcon_ws/src/stage_ros2/src/stage_node.cpp: In static member function ‘static int StageNode::callback_update_stage_world(Stg::World*, StageNode*)’:
/home/peter/colcon_ws/src/stage_ros2/src/stage_node.cpp:160:16: error: ‘ok’ is not a member of ‘rclcpp’; did you mean ‘ok’?
  160 |   if (!rclcpp::ok()) {
      |                ^~
/opt/ros/jazzy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/utilities.hpp:176:1: note: ‘ok’ declared here
  176 | ok(rclcpp::Context::SharedPtr context = nullptr);
      | ^~
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/stage_node.dir/build.make:104: CMakeFiles/stage_node.dir/src/ranger.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/stage_node.dir/build.make:118: CMakeFiles/stage_node.dir/src/camera.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/stage_node.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/stage_node.dir/src/stage_node.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/stage_node.dir/build.make:90: CMakeFiles/stage_node.dir/src/vehicle.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:139: CMakeFiles/stage_node.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< stage_ros2 [6.74s, exited with code 2]

We only receive this issue for this package, in other packages where we are having rclcpp::ok() and rclcpp::sleep_for(), we do not encounter this issue.

Did you delete your install/build space and clean rebuild not sourcing from the same terminal that touched iron?

Yes, I tried to delete the build and install folder. I think the issue is that rclcpp/utils.hpp file is creating an enum, which is having a possibility to be None, and also X11.h is creating another constant with the same name (None), and the compiler confuses them.
